# Macro to count number of specific values/strings in column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will count specific values in a given column. For example, I want to count the number of all the cells in column G that contain "candy". How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    s = "candy"
    Set r = Range("G:G")
    MsgBox wf.CountIf(r, s)
    '
    ' and if you want to count phrases including candy then:
    '
    s = "*" & s & "*"
    MsgBox wf.CountIf(r, s)
End Sub
```

**Edit**:

and to store the result in a worksheet cell:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    s = "candy"
    Set r = Range("G:G")
    s = "*" & s & "*"
    [H3] = wf.CountIf(r, s)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked very well, however it only looks for exact matches (just Candy). It doesn't count "chocolate candy" or "green candy".

Comment: Checkout the update...........use wildcards just as you would in a worksheet formula!

Comment: Perfect! One more thing, is there a way I can display this in a specific cell, say H3, instead of a message box?